Integration using slope as derivative
I have a problem described as follows:
A complex number: $G = G_1e^{-j\varphi_1} + G_2e^{jk+j\varphi_2}$
where $G_1=0.02$, $G_2 = 0.06$ and $\varphi_1=\varphi_2=0$
The angle as function of $k$: $\varphi(k) = \arg(G)$
When plotting $\varphi$ as $k$ varies from 0 to $6\pi$, I got:

The figure of phase as k varies

Figure I extracted paper


The proposed way to calculate the expected value $\varphi_{exp}$ is to use below formula:
$\varphi_{exp} = \frac{1}{2}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \frac{\partial\varphi(k)}{\partial k}dk$
I have tried to calculate the slope of the function. However, I always got value of $\varphi_{exp}$ larger than $\pi$, which is not correct.
Could anyone please help me where I did it wrong?
Thank you so much!
Here is the code for plotting the figure:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

delta_Omega_03 = np.linspace(-0.5, 0.5, 201)
kOmega_03 = np.linspace(0, 6*np.pi, 201)

g1_03 = 0.02
g2_03 = 0.06
phi1_03 = 0
phi2_03 = 0*np.pi/180

#
G = (g1_03*np.exp(-1j*phi1_03)) + (g2_03*np.exp(1j*(kOmega_03) + 1j*(phi2_03)))
phase = np.angle(G)

plt.plot(kOmega_03, phase)
plt.xlabel('k')
plt.ylabel('phi')

plt.show() ```


Notice
$$\dfrac{\partial \varphi(k)}{\partial k}\,\mathrm dk=\mathrm d\varphi$$
and thus
$$\mathbb E[\varphi]=\dfrac{1}{2}\int_{-\pi}^\pi \dfrac{\partial \varphi(k)}{\partial k}\,\mathrm dk=\dfrac{1}{2}\int_{k=-\pi}^{k=\pi} \mathrm d\varphi=\dfrac{\varphi(\pi)-\varphi(-\pi)}{2}$$
Since $\varphi_1=\varphi_2=0$,
$$G=G_1+G_2e^{jk}=G_1+G_2\cos k+jG_2\sin k\implies \varphi(k)=\arctan\left(\dfrac{G_2\sin k}{G_1+G_2\cos k}\right)$$
and so
$$\mathbb E[\varphi]=\dfrac{\varphi(\pi)-\varphi(-\pi)}{2}=0$$

In case of $G_1$ > $G_2$, the expected value of integration is 0. Can you please tell me how ?

I am not sure how but in case of $G_1 = 0$, expected value should be $\pi$.

Are you asking if it should be $\pi$ or it has to be when $G_1=0$? Notice for $G_1=0$, $\varphi$ becomes $\arctan(\tan(\pi))=0$, not $\pi$.

It has to be $\pi$ when $G_1=0$, $G_2 \neq 0$. When $G_1\neq 0$, $G_2 = 0$, it has to be $0$.

I have added a figure with some noise from a paper in blue dots, whereas the red line for theoretical calculation based on what I have posted. From that figure, they can calculate the expected value to be $0.97 \pi$ using the integral in the question.

It really depends on the branch you choose for the argument but if $G_1=0$ and $G_2\neq 0$ then $\tan\varphi=\dfrac{\text{Im}, G}{\text{Re}, G}=\tan k$ can take on different values at $k=\pi$: $\varphi(\pi)=\pi n\implies\mathbb E(\varphi)=\frac{n_1+n_2}{2}\pi$. So it is really ambiguous here.

Thanks for answering. Yes. It is ambigous. However, from the figure that contain the value extracted (blue curve), how can I retrieve back the value of expected value based on Equation, given I have two list for value of  $\varphi$ and $k_f\Omega$.

I was thinking to calculate the derivative and do integration. Could it be the solution ?
